# How to get second biggest distance from a Hashmap?

Tags: java, algorithm, image, sorting, hashmap

I am trying to get the biggest and second biggest distance in a Hashmap in Java.

Basically, from a hashmap populated with (x,y) values, I plan to pick a point, set it as a fixed point and calculate distance with this point in relation to all the other points. After all possible distances are calculated, I change the fixed point to the next element in the HashMap. With this process, I aim to get the biggest and second biggest value in a hashmap distance-wise.

```java
 HashMap<Integer, Integer> corners = getPotentialCorners(image);
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> extremeCorners = new HashMap<>();
        int Blue = new Color(0, 0, 255).getRGB();
        int currentNumberX;
        int currentNumberY;
        int pivotVarX;
        int pivotVarY;
        double distance;
        double Highest = 0;
        double Highest2 = 1;
        int xHighest = 0;
        int yHighest = 0;
        int xHighest2 = 0;
        int yHighest2 = 0;
        for (int i : corners.keySet()) {
            currentNumberX = (i);
            currentNumberY = corners.get(currentNumberX);
            for (int j : corners.keySet()) {
                pivotVarX = j;
                pivotVarY = corners.get(pivotVarX);
                distance = Math.abs(Math.sqrt(Math.pow((pivotVarX - currentNumberX), 2) + Math.pow((pivotVarY - currentNumberY), 2)));
                if (pivotVarX != currentNumberX) {
                    if ((Highest > Highest2)) {
                        xHighest = currentNumberX;
                        yHighest = currentNumberY;
                        Highest2 = distance;
                    }
                    if (distance > Highest2) {
                        Highest2 = distance;
                        xHighest2 = currentNumberX;
                        yHighest2 = currentNumberY;
                    }


                }
            }


        }
```

With this code, I debugged it, and I always get one correct point, and another point is ALWAYS (0,0). I know the issue lies with my process of getting the second highest point (Highest2, XHighest2,YHighest2), but I do not know how to fix it.

Comment: Why are you using a Map to hold the points?  You are limiting yourself to unique `x` values since Maps can't have duplicate keys.  I would suggest using a `List<Point>` where Point is a supported JDK class. You can also use Point2D.Double for floating points values.

Comment: I am using a hashmap as a list doesn't support key value pairs. I need to get the (x,y) values and apply distance formula, so that is why i chose a hashmap.

Comment: How are you going to store say (10,2) and (10,4)?  The only way I can see is to have a `HashMap<Integer,List<Integer>>` where the list is a list of  `y`s that go with the `x's`.  But that seems sort of cumbersome.

Comment: I am not too sure about that, now that you bring it up, but in all of the papers i got, the points are very close to each other, so It will just get the nearest value to that. Plus, I am using paper, and paper is rarely in a straight line, when you look at individual pixels. But, I am not sure how to store it in a list, now that you bring up the point.

Response to above comment: That is good and all and I implemented it, but now all i have to do is figure out how to work out second biggest distances. Thanks for the advice though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others pointed out, instead of a HashMap, it is better to use `List<Point>` which you can easily iterate as:

```
for (Point p: myList) {
   ...
}
```

or if you need more control on which elements to iterate over you can use an integer counter:

```
for (int j = i+1; j < corners.size(); j++) {
   Point p = corners.get(j);
   ...
}
```

instead of having to use `keySet()` and `get()` and all the problems with identical x-values mapping on the same bin.

Also, there are some trivial speed improvements possible:

- No need to use the slow `Math.sqrt()` function (or `Math.abs()` as square root is always positive) since you are only comparing larger/smaller distances. You can just compare the squared distances.
- The latest Java compiler knows how to optimize `Math.pow(int, 2)`, but to make sure you don't get the overhead of a function call, you can help the compiler by writing: `(p.x-q.x)*(p.x-q.x) + (p.y-q.y)*(p.x-q.y)`

Renaming `current` and `pivot` to `p` and `q` for conciseness, your code would look like:

```
List<Point> corners = getPotentialCorners(image);
Double highest = null;
Double highest2 = null;
Point highestP = null, highestQ = null;
Point highestP2 = null, highestQ2 = null;
for (int i = 0; i < corners.size()-1; i++) {
    Point p = corners.get(i);
    for (int j = i+1; j < corners.size(); j++) {
        Point q = corners.get(j);
        double distanceSq = (p.x-q.x)*(p.x-q.x) + (p.y-q.y)*(p.y-q.y);
        if (highest == null || distanceSq >= highest) {
            // shift highest to second highest
            highest2 = highest;
            highestP2 = highestP;
            highestQ2 = highestQ;

            highest = distanceSq;
            highestP = p;
            highestQ = q;
        } else if (highest2 == null || distanceSq > highest2) {
            highest2 = distanceSq;
            highestP2 = p;
            highestQ2 = q;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, this is super concise! I agree with you in everything, but that only gives two opposing points. So I combined two different corner detection systems to get it to work with 3-4 corners as I didn't know how to take the second greatest distance, as that would complete the diagonals.

Comment: Also @Jason , Which point should I add to the List of points?